# How to combine multiple classes in CSS

Tags: css

I am using FontAwesome on my website. To use an envelope, I have to use the following three classes like so:

```
<I class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></I>
```

Is there anyway I could combine them into a single class or create a new css file with a single rule which I could refer here?

Comment: Look at font-awesome.css ; why you want to modify it to one class?
If you are willing to write your own property as well create another class or use inheritance combining all three classes.

Comment: Don't forget to accept any answer that solves your problem and consider upvoting anything that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think, you can skip the `.fa` class, as it provides the base rule and font definition. You can, may be skip the `.fa-2x` by giving:

```css
.fa {font-size: 2em;}
```

But remember, this will make all the fonts to look 2x bigger.

If you still wish to make it a single one, use:

```css
.fa-envelope-o {
  /* copy contents from .fa */
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

On a side-note, please keep your tags in lower case.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge with those three classes style properties in to a single class, something like this

```
.fa-envelope-o{
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal FontAwesome;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

so the html is now `<i class="fa-envelope-o"></i>`.

**Note:** if you want this in all icons you should manually write like this, so that's why font-awesome follow multiple class strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I have used .less file which extends one css class with another.